# WebDriver click() not working

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the code exported to java by Selenium, and the browser is Firefox.
The problem I ran into is the click method not working, but during the runtime it looks like the button is being pressed.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dialog-confirmed")).click();
```

I have also tried sendKeys(Keys.ENTER), submit() and multiple clicks but it is still not working.

HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
           <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
      </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
     <p>By editing this product, all existing Flat loan accounts will use the newly set fees and penalties. All newly created loan accounts will use all new product settings.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">Cancel</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="dialog-confirmed">OK</button>
```

Comment: can you post a small snippet of the DOM structure this button is located in?

Comment: `<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p>By editing this product, all existing Flat loan accounts will use the newly set fees and penalties. All newly created loan accounts will use all new product settings.</p></div><div class="modal-footer">Cancel</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="dialog-confirmed">OK</button></div></div></div>`

Comment: What error you are getting when try to click?

Comment: I do not get an error, it just proceeds as if it was clicked

Comment: Could you check how many By.id("dialog-confirmed") elements webdriver does find ?

Comment: It finds only one, which is the button

Comment: It finds the button, so I believe that that is not the problem, but it seems highlighted when using click(), like when you press the mouse on it, it just doesn't seem to release it or something like that

Comment: Could you try it with js `document.getElementById('dialog-confirmed').click()`

Comment: I am translating the tests for QA from Selenium to Java, so only Java is used

Comment: This is a simple peace of javascript code, thus you have paste this like into web console in the browser and see the results, moreover webdriver can execute javascript and sometimes it is very useful. Secondly please run the next command in web browser console as well `document.getElementById('dialog-confirmed').onclick` this should show whether button has to do sth if its clicked

Comment: document.getElementById('dialog-confirmed').onclick gives null

Comment: it looks like this button doest not have any event handler which works on click event, thus is it not a problem of webdriver

Comment: can you try this
`document.getElementById('dialog-confirmed').onmousedown` and   `document.getElementById('dialog-confirmed').onmouseup`

Comment: Both of them return null

Comment: as I mentioned before there is no event handler on this button, you caould try to look for another element to which event handler is attached or probably you have to talk to dev team

Comment: Solved, by adding these two lines before driver.findElement(By.id("dialog-confirmed")).click();

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("dialog-confirmed")));

Thread.sleep(200);`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a pop-up

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

And Selenium is not throwing any `ElementNotFoundException` could it be [Same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) ? You can quickly check this by looking at the EventHandlers that are listening for this element, Selenium can't trigger JS event like `blur()` or `focus()`. I had such issues with banking iframes.

Comment: As far as I can see, only click event

Comment: The JS events may be attached to some parent element. Double check them as well. in my case the click() was executed successfully,  but no corresponding JS function was triggered to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

since this is a pop-up so just try to transfer the control to pop-up by driver.switchTo() menthod and check.

Answer (score 0):

Add some Wait Statement Before Click on button

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait((10000),TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```